Select object that has multiple relations
Example tables would be:
object



id
name




0
obj0


1
obj1


2
obj2



attr



id
description




0
attr0


1
attr1


2
attr2



link



o_id
a_id




0
0


0
1


0
2


1
1



I now want to generate a SQL that returns only objects having at least a given set of attributes. I tried JOIN, but that returns either nothing or too much.
My attempt to get an object with attributes "attr0" and "attr1" (which should match only obj0 in this case):
SELECT o.name
FROM link l
INNER JOIN object o ON o.id = l.o_id
INNER JOIN attr a ON a.id = l.a_id
WHERE a.description = 'attr0'
  AND a.description = 'attr1'

This returns nothing because after the JOIN those are unique lines. With OR instead of AND, it returns both obj0 and obj1.
The result I want to see would be only obj0, because it's the only one having attr0 and attr1.
Example (wanted) result:



o.id
o.name




0
obj0



Is there a way to do this inside SQL, instead of having to filter in code later? I feel doing it via SQL and thus in the database would make my code much faster.

I don't understand the rule you want to apply. Object 0 has two of the desired attributes and one other. Object 1 has only one of the two attributes and no other. You want to show object 1. Why?

"attr1" would denote a table column called attr1 by the way. If you want to look for a string, then use single quotes: WHERE a.description = 'attr1' ...

You want to generate a SQL that returns only obj1. It can be a simple SQL query as 'Select name FROM object WHERE id = 0'. Kindly be more specific about your use case and the relations between your tables.

Ah, sorry about the quoting. I was typing off the top.of my head. My intention was "Find an object that has at least all given attributes"

A [mcve] is supposed to specify the expected result as well.

"Given attributes" refers to all atrributes given in the query? (This is how I interpreted this n my answer.) Or does it refer to all attributes in the attribute table? (This is how d.r. interpreted this in their answer.)

@ThorstenKettner: "Given attributes" refers to, in my example, attr1 and attr2.

which makes my answer invalid.

Why have you tagged your request postgresql and sqlite? Do you need a query that is working in both DBMS for some reason? This seems a bit odd.

@ThorstenKettner That is exactly what I need, yeah. The Syntax has to work in both, because my program has to ingest different databases sadly.


Find an object that has at least all given attributes

Your example is messed up, as you look for 'attr1' and 'attr2' and want obj1 returned which only has 'attr1'.
However, you want to select an object, so select from the object table. You want to limit the result, so use a where clause. There is no need to join. Use EXISTS or IN to check whether the desired attributes exist for the object:
select *
from object
where id in (select o_id from link where a_id = (select id from attr where description = 'attr1'))
  and id in (select o_id from link where a_id = (select id from attr where description = 'attr2'));

The same with EXISTS:
select *
from object o
where exists (select null from link l where l.o_id = o.id and l.a_id = (select id from attr where description = 'attr1'))
  and exists (select null from link l where l.o_id = o.id and l.a_id = (select id from attr where description = 'attr2'));


I've added the missing parentheses.

I mistyped / mistranslated to my original column names, after correcting that error on my part it works. Thank you!

Think you need something like this - a simple aggregation grouped by object and filtered with Having clause:
Select     o.id, o.name
From       object o
Inner join link l ON( l.o_id = o.id )
Group By   o.id,  o.name
Having     Count(Distinct l.a_id) = (Select Count(id) From attr)

Just for the record:
The same result for just the 2 of attrs (if that is the issue) could be done just changing the Having clause into one of the folloving two:
Having Count(Distinct Case When l.a_id IN(0, 1) Then l.a_id End) = (Select Count(id) From attr Where id IN(0, 1))
-- OR
Having Count(Distinct Case When l.a_id !=2 Then l.a_id End) = (Select Count(id) From attr Where id != 2)

See the fiddle here.

This would match every object with a certain number of attributes, no matter which attributes they have.

@Werdck: No. This matches the objects that have all available attributes. This is how d.r. understood your request comment "Find an object that has at least all given attributes".

Oh, so this is a great thing to bookmark then, even if it doesn't solve my initial problem!

Your query is not going to work due to the "AND". There is no register that satisfies both conditions. Try to change it for an "OR"
SELECT o.name
FROM link l
INNER JOIN object o ON o.id = l.o_id
INNER JOIN attr a ON a.id = l.a_id
WHERE a.description = 'attr1'
OR a.description = 'attr2'

Or better, you can use IN
SELECT o.name
FROM link l
INNER JOIN object o ON o.id = l.o_id
INNER JOIN attr a ON a.id = l.a_id
WHERE a.description IN ('attr1','attr2');

Then you can filter for the object you want:
SELECT o.name
FROM link l
INNER JOIN object o ON o.id = l.o_id
INNER JOIN attr a ON a.id = l.a_id
WHERE a.description IN ('attr1','attr2') AND o_id=0;

If you want both ATTR:
SELECT o.id, o.name
FROM object o
JOIN link l ON o.id = l.o_id
JOIN attr a ON l.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.description IN ('attr1', 'attr2')
GROUP BY o.id, o.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) = 2;


The whole point of the query is to find objects having at least the given set of attributes. This means I can't specify the object beforehand.
My example is wanting to find all objects that at least have "attr1" and "attr2".

@Werdck Then you can try with: SELECT o.id, o.name
FROM object o
JOIN link l ON o.id = l.o_id
JOIN attr a ON l.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.description IN ('attr1', 'attr2')
GROUP BY o.id, o.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) = 2;

A simple approach would be to limit the select on o.id = 0
SELECT 
    o.name AS object_name,
    a.description AS attribute_description
FROM 
    object o
JOIN 
    link l ON o.id = l.o_id
JOIN 
    attr a ON l.a_id = a.id
WHERE 
    o.id = 0;


That would give me only object 0, correct. But I want to filter for attributes.
